# Angular / Node JS Multiple Non Blocking HTTP requests

Tags: node.js, angular, api, express, http-post

I have an API that takes around 2 minutes to complete background tasks (using Node JS + Express), in the frontend, I am requesting this API in one component, then I continue using the system, but the problem is that all other requests are pending until the first request is done.

Frontend: Angular
Backend: Node JS + Express
Problem: Long requests are blocking other requests.

Comment: Hello, you should add some code to see how you handle the requests.

Comment: In general, using the Express js

Comment: I meant your Angular code if you think that's where the problem is.